# How to correct floating point round-off error in Microsoft Excel for Macintosh 2011?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011

I'm using Microsoft Excel for Macintosh 2011 and have a spreadsheet of start and stop time spent on activities with some time differences between start and stop times that are converted into total hours in two different paths.  In one path, the whole column of time differences is summed all at once.  In a separate path, a series of subsets of the column for adjacent rows is summed into a different column (all corresponding to a single day), which is itself summed to theoretically get the same sum as the first sum.

I am subtracting these two sums and if the result is non-zero, I have conditional formatting to color it red to alert the user to an error in their spreadsheet and that the two paths/methods for summing do not agree.

My formula has been working well, however, as my spreadsheet has now grown to around 1,500 rows, I am now seeing round-off errors where the two different paths to sum up the times get slightly different values that differ by `0.000000000000909494701773` hours and the cell is being highlighted red for being non-zero.

How can I avoid the round-off drift that is occurring between these two paths to compute the same sum?  I have found that I can temporarily work around the issue by increasing one entry in the sum by 1 second and the difference returns to zero again and the cell goes green again.

Is this a known issue with Excel?  Can I cause my zero compare conditional formatting to allow more slop in the comparison?  Can I force the two paths to compute the sums to agree without adding in a second to one of the times?

Comment: I would consider using the `ROUND()` function to get rid of the rounding errors.

Comment: This is an issue in any program that uses the IEEE 754 standard and has been well documented in the past.  To deal with this in Excel, you can 1: Round to the desired level of precision.  2:  Test that the difference is not greater than a very small number.  3: Set precision as displayed option (but this will affect all of your calculaions on that page.  Option 2 is probably the "best".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge you can't avoid the rounding differences, however, you can adjust your conditional formatting to accept some slop. Select "Use formula to determine which cells to format" and try something like this:

```
=IF(ABS(A1)<0.1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

Answer (score -1):

Experimentation shows that the value 0.50001736 can be lengthened by 1's and still be evaluated by Excel as 1.01 seconds, but the moment you append a 2 to the end, it becomes 2.02 seconds. So basically, that means that 0.500017361 is one place more than one must have to distinguish between 1 and 2 seconds for Excel. That's nine decimal places so rounding final results would trim off extraneous material.

However, according to MS, Excel uses 27 places of base-10 precision plus one for sign. Yet it makes a difference whether a value is entered or it is the result of a formula:  formulas can go further in precision than hand entries. Huh. Anyhow, it will store and show 15 digits of precision. And the 27 digits means the errors, unless cumulative from individual values, will always be the last of those 15 digits. But it would be, for you, as you have, currently, 1,500 entries, so about the 11th or 12th digit.

So between 9 and 11 digits is important for you. If you evaluate the future-proofing of your methods to include, say 10^5 values someday, vs. the 10^3 today, that would cut down the high end to 9-10 digits.

So set your rounding of just the final result from each computation path to 9 or 10 decimal places. By the way, wrapping each value, somehow, in `ROUND()` hasn't much point since if it is 3, say, and their binary math makes its contribution a wee bit bigger, it will happen AFTER rounding it so it will happen anyway. So just wrap the final results of each path with the rounding.

Then comparing one result to the other should allow full expression of hours-minute-seconds yet still cut the values off before the error influence the results.

A couple other things on the subject though. One is that it seems as if one can get hundredths of a second accuracy. Yet that seems a mirage since one cannot get precisely one second, but rather 1.01 seconds seems to be the smallest unit of measure in practice. The other is it is EXACT pairings of values being used that matters, and therefore sequence as well. One could add those 1,500 values and get one result, then multiply each by two, add them all (same order), and divide the result by two and have a different result. So something like the rounding technique is the only hope.

If you use VBA and always have access to the internet, you can write a macro that goes to a website that will do higher precision math for you, load the sets of values in just the same groupings that you would have in Excel, let the website do the arithmetic, and return the results to Excel. (VBA can enter the data to any site as if you were typing it, if the site offers no more efficient method.) The results could be completely correct 15 digit values that are the max Excel will store, but were done by engines using, say, 200 digits of accuracy. Or using underlying engines that use cleverness in evaluating the values so actively avoid such errors from binary standards. Once done, it'd be pretty transparent and possibly faster than Excel, though that would hardly matter with 1,500 or 15,000 values. Even 100,000 nowadays.

Takeaway, I guess? Rounding to 9-10 digits won't hurt your accuracy at all and will strip off the errors created so they no longer affect you either.