# Order of addition matters in Excel 2010 floating point?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was entering a few numbers in Excel 2010, and noticed what appears to be a floating point issue. I took the sum of four numbers, expecting zero, and got a *very* small number, close to zero. I thought, "okay, floating point issue, sure whatever." But then I noticed if you add them in a different order, the resulting sum is zero.

**Why does adding them in a different order affect Excel**? I didn't expect this. Yes, I realize that 1.13E-13 is very small, and very close to zero. I'm wondering why the difference in calculation based on order of addition.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Raw data follows:

```
573.7   
-144.79 
-309.84 
-119.07 
1.136868E-13    =sum(A1:A4)
0.000000E+00    =A1+A2+A3+A4
1.13687E-13 =A4+A3+A2+A1
```

Comment: These [KB](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214118) [articles](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/78113) might help

Comment: I also came across this wiki article ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel  might help  it's an interesting issue for sure ...

Comment: Also see this question: http://superuser.com/questions/863192/how-to-correct-floating-point-round-off-error-in-microsoft-excel-for-macintosh-2

Comment: I see the articles about how to compensate for it. I'm more curious as to why the order matters. Did I miss that in the articles?

Comment: Excel has a fixed number of digits to work with.  If you start with large numbers, you may not have digits left for much smaller numbers, so they may not even affect the calculation.  If you start with the smallest numbers, Excel will work with those.  If you later add much larger numbers, you may lose some of the precision in the smaller numbers, but their aggregate may be large enough to be included, or at least affect the rounding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the [Evaluate formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7) function in Excel, you can see in the intermediate results that a+b+c+d is parsed from left-to-right. So, a+b+c+d is actually calculated as ((a+b)+c)+d.

In other words, first the result of a+b is calculated ([and stored in IEEE754 format](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/78113)), than c is added to that result, etc.

This explains why the result is different, because (taking into account the inaccuracy of intermediate results), ((a+b)+c)+d is not equal to a+(b+(c+d)).